# Telegram bot Keyboard not working

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram

I craete the Telegram bot on GAS, but my custom keyboard do not working.
My functon send message is below.
Thanks.

```
function sendText(text,chatId){
```

var payload = {
          'method': 'sendMessage',
          'chat_id': String(chatId),
          'text': text,
          'parse_mode': 'HTML'
        }

```
    var data = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": payload,
      "reply_markup": JSON.stringify({
        'keyboard': [['Store username']],
        'resize_keyboard':true,
        'one_time_keyboard': true
      })
    }

    // Replace with your token
    var API_TOKEN = '**********************';
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', data);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

According to telegram official api your keyboard format must be:

> Array of button rows, each represented by an Array of KeyboardButton objects

for example :

```
"reply_markup": JSON.stringify({
    'keyboard': [
                 [ ['row1-col1'] ],//row 1
                 [ ['row2-col1'],['row2-col2'] ] //row 2
                 ],
    'resize_keyboard':true,
    'one_time_keyboard': true
  })
```

Comment: Note: If you are debugging on your computer, it seems reply keyboards don't work on web.telegram.org but work fine on the app.